# WPF ScrollViewer resize problem

Tags: wpf, layout

I've got a scrollviewer in a WPF window that is resizing according to its contents no matter what I do.  This is kind of a problem since it will resize my window as well, and in my opinion defeats the purpose of a scrollviewer.

The window in question has its SizeToContent set to "WidthAndHeight" which I know can be set to "Manual" to resolve the scrollviewer issues, but then I have to go and fiddle with my window layout.

Is there any way to get the best of both worlds here?  All I want is for the scrollviewer to stay the same (its current) size any time its content changes.

**EDIT:**
If you really need to see it.....

```
<Window SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
  <Grid Width="200" Name="ThinkBeforeSpeaking">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBars="Auto" HorizontalScrollBars="Auto">
      <ContentControl Content={Binding AnythingYouCanImagine}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Doesn't need to be a content control inside of the viewer, just anything bigger than the window in either dimension.

Answer (score 3):

I've just come across this problem myself, and I've found a suitable solution in wrapping the ScrollViewer in a Canvas, so that it doesn't take part in the measuring pass, and telling the ScrollViewer to use the ActualHeight and ActualWidth of the Canvas so that it takes up all the space the Canvas has been given:

```xml
<Window SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
  <Grid Width="200" Name="ThinkBeforeSpeaking">
    <Canvas>
      <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBars="Auto" HorizontalScrollBars="Auto"
        Height="{Binding Parent.ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Width="{Binding Parent.ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <ContentControl Content={Binding AnythingYouCanImagine}"/>
      </ScrollViewer>
    </Canvas>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

As it stands, there's nothing telling the window to have any height at all, so either one of the existing controls (Window, Grid or Canvas) needs a defined Height/MinHeight, or other controls need to be added which will provide their own Height/MinHeight.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want your Window to start sized large enough to fit it's content, but then if the content changes it will not resize.

If so, you'd need to reset the SizeToContent option when the Window is loaded, like so:

```
public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += (s, e) => { this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual; };
}
```

Comment: no, I don't want the inner content of the scrollviewer to dictate the size of the window.

Comment: @A.R. - Then why use the WidthAndHeight setting? Are there other controls outside the ScrollViewer that you would like to dictate the size?

Comment: Typically yes.  I gave a contrived example to illustrate the heart of the problem, rather than having the community become distracted with unrelated details.  I just want the scrollviewer to not resize itself after content is added to it.

Comment: @A.R. - I'm not sure it is unrelated. If the Window contains a ScrollViewer, which contains your content, then using WidthAndHeight makes no sense unless you want your content to dictate the size of the window. If there are other controls outside the ScrollViewer, then I could see the point of the question (as you want to exclude certain content from the WidthAndHeight "calculation").

Comment: No, it is quite unrelated.  I really just want to find a way to get the scrollviewer to act the same regardless of window sizing rules.

Comment: Holy moly! This handles such issue as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58998542/why-size-of-controls-are-wrong-before-resize-wpf Is that a BUG?

Comment: Also, make sure it might should be included exactly in UserControl's constructor

Comment: Beware, UserControl Window's position might be changed even if 'WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"' exists!

Answer (score 0):

In your example you're using the WidthAndHeight behavior for your Window. The Window's Width will expand to the 200px you set on your Grid, but then you have no control to dictate which Height the Window needs to have.

Consequently, the Window's Height will resize to the ScrollViewer's content, unless you specify a fixed Height or MaxHeight for your ScrollViewer or Grid (Or any other container between the Window and the ScrollViewer).

```
<Window SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
   <Grid Width="200" Height="150" Name="ThinkBeforeSpeaking">
      <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBars="Auto" HorizontalScrollBars="Auto">
         <ContentControl Content={Binding AnythingYouCanImagine}"/>
      </ScrollViewer>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Think of it, which Height would the Window have otherwise? None? Infinite? There's nothing in your XAML that specifies it.